# javascript return statement to stop executing the rest of statements

Tags: javascript, scope, return

I have scenario where I want to break the next function call if the previous function has return statement but I can see it is executing next function call even after I have return statement in below function named "b".

```
function main(){
  a()
  b();
  c();
}

function a(){
  console.log("function a call!!");
}
function b(){
  console.log("function b call!!");
  return function(){return 0;}
}
function c(){
  console.log("function c call!!");
}

main()
```

Outout :

```
'function a call!!'
'function b call!!'
'function c call!!'
```

Expected output:

```
'function a call!!'
'function b call!!'
```

Can someone can explain me what is right way to do here?

Comment: your `main` function should have return statement to break that function. Here retun on function `b` will return something from `b` to `main` function and not out of `main` function.

Comment: Ideally I want to block "c" function call if "b" function calls based on some condition. if my b function is as below: function b() { return; }... still it doesnt work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do control flow on a caller function from a callee function. your code just returns a `function` from `b()`, but that function is never executed, and even if it is, it won't have the expected behavior. If you want to interrupt `main`, have to do it in `main` itself:

```
function main(){
  a()
  const bReturnValue = b();
  if(bReturnValue <some condition>) {
      return;
  }
  c();
}

function a(){
  console.log("function a call!!");
}
function b(){
  console.log("function b call!!");
  return function(){return 0;}
}
function c(){
  console.log("function c call!!");
}

main()
```

Comment: Thanks Guerric for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t cancel the function call of C since you don’t check for what b returns. Let b return true for example, and check with

```
let resultB = b();
if(!resultB) c();
```